# Order by a field which is selected as part of a concatenation - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to order by a a field which is part of a concatenation.

For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(field1 ||' '||field2) AS field3 from Table ORDER BY field1;
```

Is this possible to do in some other way? I get an error stating that I cannot order by a field which is not selected.

Is there a way to select a field but make it invisible so that I can ORDER BY it?

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done either using a subquery or a CTE:

Subquery:

```
SELECT c.field3
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(field1 ||' '||field2) AS field3 from Table) c
ORDER BY c.field3;
```

CTE:

```
WITH ConcatTable AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT(field1 ||' '||field2) AS field3 from Table
) 
SELECT field3 FROM ConcatTable ORDER BY field3;
```

It could also be done by simply repeating the selected expression, though I don't prefer that because of the code duplication:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(field1 ||' '||field2)
FROM Table
ORDER BY field1 ||' '||field2;
```

====== Edit =========

As pointed out in comments, ordering by the concatenated field is not quite the same as ordering just by field1. If you really did want to sort just by field1, you would have to do something like this:

Subquery:

```
SELECT c.field3
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT field1, (field1 ||' '||field2) AS field3 from Table) c
ORDER BY c.field1;
```

CTE:

```
WITH ConcatTable AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT field1, (field1 ||' '||field2) AS field3 from Table
) 
SELECT field3 FROM ConcatTable ORDER BY field1;
```

Comment: That does not order by `field1`

Comment: Field1 is the first component of the concatenated expression, so it will order by field1; it's just that there will also be a secondary sort by field2, which I would hope is not disqualifying. Question for the OP: is there some reason why you mustn't include any mention of field2 in the ORDER BY?

Comment: not in all cases, no. As a counter-example consider 2 rows, #1 is `('a','c')` and #2 is `('ab','c')` with `lc_collate=en_US.utf-8`. Sorting by field1 gives #1 then #2, whereas sorting by `field1||' '||field2` gives #2 then #1.